# Solve diff eq. $\dot x=\frac{t}{1+2x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked to solve the following differential equation:
$$
\dot x=\frac{t}{1+2x},\qquad x(-1)=0.
$$
So I started as follows:
$$\begin{align}
(1+2x)\dot x&=t\\
\int_0^x 1+2x\ dx&=\frac{1}{2}t^2\big\rvert_{-1}^t\\
x+x^2\big\rvert_0^x&=\frac{1}{2}t^2-\frac{1}{2}\\
x+x^2&=\frac{1}{2}t^2-\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}$$
However, I'm not sure how to solve it from here. Could someone help me out?

Comment: You can try separation of variables, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables

Comment: The variables are separated...

Comment: Ah sorry lol, then just solve this as a quadratic function:)

Comment: Here is a useful formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Reduced_quadratic_equation

Comment: Oh, I somehow am not used to using the quadratic formula with variables, but yea, why not? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there: $$x^2+x=t^2/2-1/2$$, $$(x+\frac{1}{2})^2=\frac{t^2}{2}-\frac{1}{4}$$, $$x=-\frac{1}{2}+ \sqrt{\frac{t^2}{2}-\frac{1}{4}}$$

Comment: You have 2 solutions; only 1 matches the initial condition.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. Corrected.